# JSF input element value leads to ui crash after page refresh

Tags: jsf, primefaces, refresh

I have a model for a ui mask of input fields. This model is rendered with ui:repeat. The model is grid oriented so there is a class SearchMaskRow which aggregates SearchMaskColumn. A SearchMaskColumn has a member Property which itself has a member value of type Object.

Here the important part of the iteration:

```
<p:panelGrid id="searchMaskFieldsStaticGridId" styleClass="searchMaskFieldsGrid"
    rendered="#{not curSearch.isClosable()}">
    <ui:repeat value="#{curSearch.getSearchMaskDescription().getRows()}" var="curRow">
        <p:row styleClass="searchMaskRow">
            <ui:repeat value="#{curRow.elements}" var="curElement">
                <p:column colspan="#{curElement.columnSpan}"
                    styleClass="#{curElement.isOfDataTypeStr('label') ? 'searchMaskLabelColumn' : 'searchMaskInputColumn'}">

                    <!--  label -->
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{curElement.property.getValue()} #{curElement.colonOnRightSide ? ':' : ''}" for="colInputTextId"
                        rendered="#{curElement.isOfDataTypeStr('label')}" />

                    <!-- date data type -->
                    <p:calendar id="colCalendarId" styleClass="searchMaskInputElement" value="#{curElement.property.value}"
                        rendered="#{curElement.isOfDataTypeStr('date')}" showButtonPanel="true" showOn="button"
                        pages="#{curElement.getCalendarPages()}" size="#{curElement.getWidthInCharacters()}" />

                    <!-- string and integer data type -->
                    <p:inputText id="colInputTextId" styleClass="searchMaskInputElement" value="#{curElement.property.value}"
                        rendered="#{curElement.isOfDataTypeStr('string') or curElement.isOfDataTypeStr('integer')}"
                        size="#{curElement.getWidthInCharacters()}" />

                </p:column>
            </ui:repeat>
            <ui:param name="unfilledColumnsCount"
                value="#{searchBL.determinedUnfilledColumns(curSearch.getSearchMaskDescription(), curRow)}" />
            <p:column colspan="#{unfilledColumnsCount}" rendered="#{unfilledColumnsCount gt 0}">
                <h:outputLabel value="" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:panelGrid>
```

On first access of the ui all works. But if the page is refresh by clicking the browsers refresh button or submitting the url, I get the following exception:

```
13:44:17,507 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-/0.0.0.0:9090-2) Error Rendering View[/icarchive/views/main.xhtml]: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /icarchive/sections/firstSearchTab.xhtml @30,95 value="#{curElement.property.value}": The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'property'.
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:170) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat$SavedState.populate(UIRepeat.java:829) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.saveChildState(UIRepeat.java:370) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.saveChildState(UIRepeat.java:376) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.saveChildState(UIRepeat.java:376) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.saveChildState(UIRepeat.java:376) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.saveChildState(UIRepeat.java:356) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:441) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:483) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:990) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:155) [primefaces-5.1.12.jar:5.1.12]
at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:104) [primefaces-5.1.12.jar:5.1.12]
at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableLayout(PanelGridRenderer.java:65) [primefaces-5.1.12.jar:5.1.12]
at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:37) [primefaces-5.1.12.jar:5.1.12]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:881) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabContent(TabViewRenderer.java:309) [primefaces-5.1.12.jar:5.1.12]
at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:283) [primefaces-5.1.12.jar:5.1.12]
at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:132) [primefaces-5.1.12.jar:5.1.12]
at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:71) [primefaces-5.1.12.jar:5.1.12]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:881) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:851) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:79) [primefaces-5.1.12.jar:5.1.12]
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66) [primefaces-5.1.12.jar:5.1.12]
at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49) [primefaces-5.1.12.jar:5.1.12]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:881) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:439) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleWrapper.render(CodiLifecycleWrapper.java:126) [myfaces-extcdi-jsf20-module-impl-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105) [primefaces-5.1.12.jar:5.1.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at ip.client.commons.web.xss.filter.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:53) [ip-filter-xss-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:115) [omnifaces-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1-20140603]
at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77) [omnifaces-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1-20140603]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at ip.client.web.filter.commons.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:103) [ip-filter-commons-5.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:115) [omnifaces-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1-20140603]
at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77) [omnifaces-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1-20140603]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:149) [omnifaces-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1-20140603]
at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77) [omnifaces-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1-20140603]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
```

Probably there is a problem with the submit of the values. But I debugged the Property.setValue(value:Object) method and there werecorrect objects set.

If I understand this exception correctly, the list of SearchMaskElements inside SearchMaskRow (which is curElement in facelet) is of type string. But I cannot imagine how this be. It is a List and also there is no set access to this list only read on iteration. SearchMaskRow even hasn't a setter setElements() to put the string inside.
Someone has an idea? I have no clue.

I am using:
mojarra 2.1.23
primefaces 5.1.12
de.odysseus.juel 2.2.6

Regards
Oliver

Comment: The corresponding backing bean is absent in the question. Here, `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /icarchive/sections/firstSearchTab.xhtml @30,95 value="#{curElement.property.value}": The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'property'.` it states that `curElement` is a String type property  (you are referring through the expression `#{curElement.property.value}` in `<p:calendar>` and `<p:inputText>`) and needless to say that the class `String` does not have a property named `property` defined/declared inside.

Comment: curElement is a class always of my own type SearchMaskColumn. This class has a member Property and a Property has a member with name value of type Object. So the value inside the Property can be a string, that's ok, but never can be SearchMaskColumn be a string.

Comment: `curElement` is obtained from `#{curRow.elements}` which in turn is obtained from `#{curSearch.getSearchMaskDescription().getRows()}`. Are you sure that all of these expressions return a correct/desired type? The message symptoms clearly state that `curElement` is a String type object. Thus, you cannot do `curElement.property` because `curElement` does have `property`. (As a side note, you could achieve the same thing using other nice JSF/PrimeFaces iterator components such as `<p:dataTable>`, `<p:dataGrid>`, `<p:dataList>` etc instead of using independent `<ui:repeat>`).

Comment: Yes I am also very confused about this exception message too. curElement cannot be a string. I even have not a setter  for it only a getter and I generate a list with generic type SearchMaskElement. But maybe there is another issue with my approach. The code I posted is inside a p:tabView in each tab. I have only one form for all tabs. This is probably wrong?

Comment: It is legitimate to have that code inside a `<p:tabView>` (nevertheless, I did not try a stray `<p:row>` but this should not be an issue either way). Did you put the required logic inside `getRows()` here in this expression - `#{curSearch.getSearchMaskDescription().getRows()}`? If it is then, please consider moving it in its own place usually a method decorated with `@PostConstruct`, since getters are supposed to be invoked several times by nature.

Comment: What do you mean with required logic. #{curSearch.getSearchMaskDescription().getRows()} getRows is only an accessor for a List<SearchMaskRow>. Isn't that correct?

Comment: It is correct. I asked just because many a times, people are seen implementing business logic incorrectly in accessor methods even though there is no special case to do so.

Comment: Ok thanks for your comments. But I don't know what is the problem in my case. Maybe this exception message is misleading and I have debug a little more.

Comment: Isolate some portion of the code alternatively, even if careful debugging does not help. I had to do this several times in the past.

Comment: I already did this and identified that the nested ui:repeat inside dynamic tabs in tabView is the problem. Now I gave each tab a own form and leave the tabView formless to avoid form nesting. Also I changed some names of iteration variables defined with var. I do not know what exactly was the trick. Probably the forms, but now it is working as expected :)

Answer (score -1):

you must change the name of the variable "value", I think that there are a contribution between the attribut 'value' and your variable.

good luck

Comment: Tried it with a changed name without success. Same exception. If it is the name then the 1st rendering of the ui would probably also not work I think.